# Logstash install error: can't get unique system GID (no more available GIDs)

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am trying to install logstash with yum on a red hat vm, I already have the logstash.repo file setup according to the guide and i ran

`yum install logstash`

but I get the following error after it downloads everything

```
...

logstash-2.3.2-1.noarch.rpm                              |  72 MB     00:52     
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test
Transaction Test Succeeded
Running Transaction
groupadd: Can't get unique system GID (no more available GIDs)
useradd: group 'logstash' does not exist
error: %pre(logstash-1:2.3.2-1.noarch) scriptlet failed, exit status 6
Error in PREIN scriptlet in rpm package 1:logstash-2.3.2-1.noarch
error:   install: %pre scriptlet failed (2), skipping logstash-1:2.3.2-1
  Verifying  : 1:logstash-2.3.2-1.noarch                                    1/1 

Failed:
  logstash.noarch 1:2.3.2-1                                                     

Complete!
```

I can't find much information about this. Any suggestions?

Comment: what should those values be?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

groupadd determines **gids** for the creation of regular groups from the **/etc/login.defs** file.

In my centos 6 box. **/etc/login.defs** contains following two lines:

```
#
# Min/max values for automatic gid selection in groupadd
#
GID_MIN                   500
GID_MAX                 60000
```

For system accounts add these two lines to your **/etc/login.defs**

```
# System accounts
SYS_GID_MIN               100
SYS_GID_MAX               499
```

Comment: i have those values too, but what should i change?

Comment: Updated the answer set SYS_GID_MIN and SYS_GID_MAX values.

Answer (score 1):

I updated the SYS_GID_MAX Value and it worked for me.